# Trying to pass input_data as a json request for API

Tags: zapier

Below is my API, I am trying to pass the information from an input data sheet that contains proper emailaddress, firstname, and lastname, however when i am passing that to api it doesn't get resolved. what am I doing wrong here

> import requests
>
> url = "https://api.ZZZ.us/v2/users"
>
> payload = "{\r\n  \"action\": \"create\",\r\n  \"user_info\": {\r\n
>   \"email\": \"**input_data['emailaddress']**\",\r\n    \"type\": 1,\r\n
>   \"first_name\": \"**input_data['firstname']**\",\r\n    \"last_name\":
>   \"**input_data['lastname']**\"\r\n  }\r\n}" headers = {
>       'Accept': "application/json, application/xml",
>       'Content-Type': "application/json",
>       'Authorization': "Bearer XXXXX",
>       'cache-control': "no-cache",
>       'Postman-Token': "ab32d014-97fb-499e-8adf-c1baf49871e2"
>       }
>
> response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload,
>   headers=headers)
>
> print(response.text) output = {'id': 1333121, 'response':
>   response.text}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to make sure your JSON is valid. For this reason please encode it well. I tried this and worked out. you should be sending this.

```
{
    "action": "create",
    "user_info": {
        "email": "mymail@gmail.com",
        "first_name": "mike",
        "last_name": "tyson"
    }
}
```

This is the code modifications.

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://enzi2vbg2aau9.x.pipedream.net/"

input_data = ["mymail@gmail.com", 'mike', 'tyson']

payload = json.dumps({
  "action": "create",
  "user_info": {
    "email": input_data[0],
    "first_name": input_data[1],
    "last_name": input_data[2]
  }
})

headers = { 
  'Accept': "application/json, application/xml", 
  'Content-Type': "application/json", 
  'Authorization': "Bearer XXXXX", 
  'cache-control': "no-cache", 
  'Postman-Token': "ab32d014-97fb-499e-8adf-c1baf49871e2" 
  }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text) # output = {'id': 1333121, 'response': response.text}
```

if you need to send a string from somewhere else that comes as your example payload then you need to use json.loads(payload) please see this example.

```
payload = '''{
    "action": "create",
    "user_info": {
        "email": "mymail@gmail.com",
        "first_name": "mike",
        "last_name": "tyson"
    }
}'''

payload = json.loads(payload)
payload = json.dumps(payload)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, this worked out. import json did the trick :)